# This resource is only for developers enrolled in a developer program Error in logining

Tags: xcode, account

i'be been using my developer account for 2 month but today warning me that this is not a developer account :|

how is this possible ?

complete warning : Access Unavailable

This resource is only for developers enrolled in a developer program or members of an organization’s team in a developer program.

do they banned my account?? what I've done wrong ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Has anyone solved this?

Comment: I cannot believe that this question has no answer in 9 months! My impression is that free certificates do not exist anymore although this page still shows the free developer certificate: https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev21218dfd6.